# Space Marine squads and "Split Fire" rule

Tags: warhammer-40k

With the 6th edition rules, squads must all fire upon the same unit. An exception is made if the unit contains at least one model with the "split fire" rule (6ED, page 42).

Neither the Devastors, nor Tactical squads, in the Dark Angels codex (6ED, page 103), nor in the Blood Angels codex (5ED, page 95) have the "split fire" rule. As a side note, some Dark Angel units have it but no Blood Angels have it at all.

This [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlC-8_Dd-Tg) (starting at 6:50) suggests that the squads have "Split Fire".

**First question**: where in the 6ED rules is it specified that Devastator squads have split fire?

**Second question**: do Tactical squads have split fire? If so, where in the 6ED rules is that specified?

Comment: I'm not 100% on this (and I can't check the video right now) but maybe they mean combat squadding a 10 man devastator squad? This means you would have two units of 5 marines with 2 heavy weapons- then you could fire at two different targets, but still only take up one spot on the force org chart. I'm fairly sure neither devastator nor tactical squads have split fire.

Comment: I've edited the post to add the time for the video

Answer (score 3):

Devastator does not have split fire. No marine devastator-equivalent except Space Wolves Long Fangs have the ability to target more than one unit. Fritz either made a mistake or he meant that even if they were to get split fire for free, that's still a lot of points in one unit.